# bash use second argument of previous command

Tags: bash

how I can use the second argument of previous command in a new command ?

example, with

```
$ mkdir test
```

I make a directory, how I can use the name of directory for change to this ?

```
$ mkdir test && cd use_var
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With history expansion, you can refer to arbitrary words in the current command line

```
mkdir dir1 && cd "!#:1"
# 0     1   2  3  4
```

`!#` refers to the line typed so far, and `:1` refers to word number one (with `mkdir` starting at 0).

If you use this in a script (i.e., a non-interactive shell), you need to turn history expansion on with `set -H` and `set -o history`.

Comment: And `!` refers to the previous line. `!:1` is synonymous with `!^`, and `!$` is the last argument on the previous line.

Answer (score 6):

`$_` is the last (right-most) argument of the previous command.

```
mkdir gash && cd "$_"
```

(I don't create files or directories called `test`, that's the name of a shell built-in and can cause confusions)

Answer (score 2):

Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> places the last argument of previous command on the current place of cursor. Tested in `bash` shell and `ksh` shell.

Comment: Different effects depending on `set -o emacs` (default in bash) and `set -o vi` (default in ksh).  In emacs editing mode it does as you say, in vi editing mode it repeats the whole of the previous statement. (tested in Bash 4 and ksh 93)

Answer (score 1):

I use functions for this. Type this in your shell:

```
mkcd() { mkdir "$1" ; cd "$1" ; }
```

Now you have a new command `mkcd`.

If you need this repeatedly, put the line into the file `~/.bash_aliases` (if you use `bash`; other shells use different names).

Comment: `.bash_aliases` is not automatically recognized by `bash`, so you can put this in any file and make sure it is sourced by `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.

Comment: This will work on at least openSUSE and Ubuntu (so it should work on Debian, too).